# What happens to the babies that the white walkers collect?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We all see that Craster's last son was turned into a White Walker, but still haven't seen any kid/infant White Walker or wight. It seems kinda weird, what will the White Walkers do with kids in their army? I don't think they can fight, so why turn them? We've seen that dead people become wights and they don't age, so do these babies grow old or something?

Comment: I guess the correct answer is We don't know. As far as the show is concerned i think showing undead babies is a bit too much and can even cause legal issues maybe. But they can either eat them, sacrifice them or even train them. Simply we don't know anything about them. In the books which is the canonical source of this show, we didn't even see that battle in Hardhome.

Comment: Baby wights would probably be useless since they are 'dead'. But the baby white walkers presumably grow up to be adult white walkers...

Comment: In season 5 episode 8 "Hardhome" we actually _do_ see child wights. They fight just like the other wights.